# Create pandas dataframe with hundred columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a dataframe from multiple lists. For example, each list consists of 240 data. then these 240 data will be columns. so, for example I have 10 lists, then the size of the dataframe is (10, 240).

Until I made 11 lists, the dataframes that were created were still as desired [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvQVv.png). when creating a dataframe with more than 11 lists, the dataframe looks weird (it's just one column) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUMWX.png). What should i do?

```
a = []
for p, i in mfcc[:11]:
    b = []
    for j in i:
        for k in j:
            b.append(k)
    a.append(b)

pd.DataFrame(np.array(a, dtype=object))
```

[image: pict 1]

[image]

Comment: what is `fr` in the first picture, and why don't you put it in the second one?

Comment: please provide a fully (minimal) reproducible example. What are `mfcc`, `df`? Why are you using an intermediate array?